# How to embed transparent videos to Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, video, transparency

The problem is, i want to create a pretty neat help system which has a person talking about functions of the software in front of buttons etc on the screen.
BUT,
as far as i understand there is no alpha-transparency for videos supported by silverlight.

Is there any good ideas to implement the same effect?
Also the performance is a big issue here, if i can manage to make this happen in GPU, i'll be more happy :)

Thanks guys...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can shoot your video with a Green screen background then a Chroma Key Effect ought to be able to deliver what you need.  See [Silverlight Chroma Key effect](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SLChromaKeyEffect).

Comment: this looks promising, also it says that it's done at gpu, which is what i want, thanks Anthony.

Answer (score 0):

Seems it's possible: http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/17230/71330.aspx

But I'm almost sure there's no way to get the GPU to render it with alpha channel...